# "Break" delete assigned variable?

Tags: ruby, rspec, break

I can't understand why champion is Hermione at first and after the break, champions is becoming nil...
Is there a problem using break?

here is my code :

```
def pair(users_with_meeting, paired_users, ordered_keys,week)    

  ordered_keys.each do |key|    
    candidates = users_with_meeting[key] - paired_users  
    unless candidates.empty?  
      champion = candidates.first 
      puts "ok"
      puts champion.inspect.to_s   
      break    
    end     
  end   

  puts champion.inspect.to_s   

  if champion
    meetings.create! week: week, paired_user: champion
    champion.meetings.create! week: week, paired_user: self
  else
    []
  end

end
```

and here is what appears in my terminal :

```
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/models/user_spec.rb"=>[117]}}
ok    
#<User id: 1265, email: "Hermione.Granger@example.com", first_name: "Hermione", last_name: "Granger", uid: "Hermione.Granger@example.com", active: true, admin: false, created_at: "2013-09-15 18:09:16", updated_at: "2013-09-15 18:09:16", reset_date: "2013-04-22">
F

Failures:

  1) test
     Failure/Error: ginny.pair(User.with_meeting_for(week[1]), [], User.with_meeting_for(week[1]).keys.sort.reverse, week[2])
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `champion' for #<User:0x007f85189179f0>
     # ./app/models/user.rb:64:in `pair'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Ask yourself: where does my `pair` function end?

Comment: Please paste the whole code of `pair` method. It would be best if it was also indented properly.

Comment: `puts champion.inspect.to_s` is unnecessarily awkward, because `inspect` returns a string that doesn't need converting, and `puts champion.inspect` is the same as `p champion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because you define `champion` local variable inside the scope bound with the block you pass into the `each` method. Outside this block, the variable value becomes `nil`. To prevent this, you could predefine the variable before calling `each` method, like this:

```
def pair(users_with_meeting, paired_users, ordered_keys,week)
  champion = ''
  ordered_keys.each do |key|    
    candidates = users_with_meeting[key] - paired_users  
    unless candidates.empty?  
      champion = candidates.first 
      puts "ok"
      puts champion.inspect.to_s   
      break    
    end     
  end   
  puts champion.inspect.to_s   
  if champion
    meetings.create! week: week, paired_user: champion
    champion.meetings.create! week: week, paired_user: self
  else
    []
  end
end
```